# Elixir: shortcut access to method/macro from another module

Tags: elixir

So, I have mix project, with module `Uploader.Server` and module `Uploader.Utility`.

`Uploader.Utility` defines `request` macro. Problem is that I can't access it like this in `Uploader.Server`, I can only call `Uploader.Utility.request`, which is very inconvinient, as server module provides shell interface and `request` is going to be a common argument for commands.

I can just put this macro in `Uploader.Server` module, but logically it does not belong there.

Can I somehow provide access to this macro `Uploader.Server` just by inner name, not outer, something like alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Kernel.SpecialForms.import/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2).

Example:

```
defmodule Uploader.Utility do
  defmacro request(name) do
    quote do
      def unquote(name)(), do: :ok
    end
  end
end

defmodule Uploader.Server do
  require Uploader.Utility
  import Uploader.Utility, only: [request: 1]

  request(:hello)
end

IO.inspect Uploader.Server.hello
```

prints

```
:ok
```